# Find and Add Missing Column Values Based on Index Increment Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Good Afternoon!

I have a pandas dataframe with an index and a count.

```
dictionary = {1:5,2:10,4:3,5:2}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary , orient = 'index' , columns = ['count'])
```

What I want to do is check from df.index.min() to df.index.max() that the index increment is 1.  If a value is missing like in my case the 3 is missing then I want to add 3 to the index with a 0 in the count.

The output will look like the below df2 but done in a programmatic fashion so I can use it on a much bigger dataframe.

RESULTS EXAMPLE DF:

```
dictionary2 = {1:5,2:10,3:0,4:3,5:2}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary2 , orient = 'index' , columns = ['count'])
```

Thank you much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the index is sorted:

```
df = df.sort_index()
```

Create an array that starts from the minimum index to the maximum index

```
   complete_array = np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 1)
```

Reindex, fill the null value with 0, and optionally change the dtype to Pandas Int:

```
df.reindex(complete_array, fill_value=0).astype("Int16")

    count
1   5
2   10
3   0
4   3
5   2
```